# JQuery each function to fill array with attributes from HTML images

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, each

I'm trying to load an array filled with the src attribute from a series of img tags in my HTML document.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    JQuery Slider
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
    <h1 class="dark-header">2014 Salt Lake Comic Con FanX</h1>
        <div id="background-img">
            <img src="img/img01.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img02.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img03.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img04.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img05.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img06.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img07.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img08.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img09.jpg"/>
        </div>
                <div>
            <img src="img/img10.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    var source = new Array();


    $('img').each(function(attr) {
        source.push($('img').attr('src'))
    });



    console.log(source)

});//end document.ready
```

The output to the console is an array of 10 elements, but only using the first img attribute. I'm not sure how to get the each function to go through all elements and push them to the array.

Comment: you need to use 'this' inside of the loop $(this).attr('src')

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var source = [];
$('img').each(function() {
  source.push( this.getAttribute('src') );
});
```

In your `each` code, you re-select the entire group with `$('img')` so it is only adding the first one of THAT Selection to your array.

OR

If you aren't using jQuery for anything else, you could do it in straight javascript like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getImgAttr);

var source = [];

function getImgAttr() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  [].forEach.call(imgs, function( img ) {
     source.push( img.src);
  });
}
```

Comment: I was going to post the jQuery version of this, which would be the same, except:  `source.push($(this).attr('src'));`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `$('img').attr('src')` will always return the  value of the first element in the collection of elements.

As pointed out in comments , you need to look at specific instances within your loop

Another way you can do this is using `map()` which will create the array for you

```
var source = $('img').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s0mp7xw1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 'this' while inside the loop to reference the image, otherwise you are getting the reference to first 'img ' tag.

it should be like this:

```
$('img').each(function(attr) {
    source.push($(this).attr('src'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function needs to accept a second param...

The first param is the current index of the array and the second param is the object at that index.

You may also utilize the keyword `this` as suggested above.

Based on my answer your code would look like this:

```
$('img').each(function(i, img) {
    source.push($(img).attr('src'));
    // alternatively -> source.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

A second option you may like and puts what you're trying to do onto a single line would be to use the [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function...

```
var source = $.map($('img'), function(img) { return $(img).attr('src'); });
```